# Count id_employee in another column

Tags: sql

Could someone help me how to count the number of times an employee 
"id" is next to the another employee in the "executive" column?

In the first picture I am sending the table and the results I want. In the second picture the result I have

```
SELECT id_employee, lastname, COUNT(id_employee) 
FROM employees 
WHERE id_employee IN (SELECT executive FROM employees) 
GROUP BY lastname, id_employee;
```

1

[image: image 1]

2

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a self-join:

```
select iemp.d_employee, emp.last_name, subordinates
from employee as emp
join
 ( -- count per executive
   select executive, count(*) as subordinates
   from employee
   group by executive
 ) as emp_count
on emp.id_employee = emp_count.executive
```

When you switch to an Outer Join you can include employees which are not executives:

```
select id_employee, last_name, 
   coalesce(subordinates, 0)  -- to get zero instead of NULL 
from employee as emp
left join
 ( -- count per executive
   select executive, count(*) as subordinates
   from employee
   group by executive
 ) as emp_count
on emp.id_employee = emp_count.executive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query, simple and sweet.

```
SELECT * INTO #EMPLOYEE FROM 
(SELECT 1001 as ID_EMP,'JAMES' as LASTNAME,NULL as EXECUTIVE
UNION
SELECT 1002 as ID_EMP,'JENSEN' as LASTNAME,1001 as EXECUTIVE
UNION
SELECT 1003 as ID_EMP,'RUDY' as LASTNAME,1001 as EXECUTIVE
UNION
SELECT 1004 as ID_EMP,'CZARNY' as LASTNAME,1002 as EXECUTIVE
UNION
SELECT 1005 as ID_EMP,'RAMBUS' as LASTNAME,1002 as EXECUTIVE
UNION
SELECT 1006 as ID_EMP,'ADAM' as LASTNAME,1003 as EXECUTIVE
)A

SELECT ID_EMP,A.COUNT FROM (SELECT EXECUTIVE,COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM #EMPLOYEE GROUP BY EXECUTIVE)A LEFT JOIN #EMPLOYEE E
ON E.ID_EMP = A.EXECUTIVE
```